# mysql select with order by using filesort no index used

Tags: mysql, indexing, temporary, filesort

Sorry fot long post but this is really strange and I am close to give it up. 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `endu_results` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `base_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `base_nr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `base_yob` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `endu_results_206a6355` (`base_name`),
 KEY `endu_results_63df4402` (`base_nr`),
 KEY `base_yob` (`base_yob`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3424028 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;enter code here
```

and 2nd:

```
CREATE TABLE `endu_resultinterest` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `result_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `endu_resultinterest_3b529087` (`result_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `result_id_refs_id_19e24435` FOREIGN KEY (`result_id`) REFERENCES `endu_results` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48590 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

There are about 2mln records in endu_resultstable and less then 100K i endu_resultinterest. I have slow query:

```
explain select base_yob from endu_resultinterest 
inner join endu_results 
on (endu_results.id = endu_resultinterest.result_id) 
order by endu_results.base_yob;

1   SIMPLE  endu_resultinterest index   endu_resultinterest_3b529087    endu_resultinterest_3b529087    4   NULL    47559   Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

**The question is: Why mysql is using this index: endu_resultinterest_3b529087 - but it should use base_yob - this is where sorting is requested ?**

To test it further I have manaully created 2 additional identical tables *endu_testresults* and *endu_testresultintrest* and filled those with some records:

```
CREATE TABLE `endu_testresults` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `base_yob` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `base_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `base_nr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `endu_testresults_a65b2616` (`base_yob`),
KEY `endu_testresults_ba0ab39c` (`base_name`),
KEY `endu_testresults_d75ba04d` (`base_nr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So I go again for explain:

```
explain select base_yob from endu_testresultinterest 
inner join endu_testresults 
on (endu_testresults.id = endu_testresultinterest.result_id) 
order by endu_testresults.base_yob;
```

and **suprise suprise**:

```
 1  SIMPLE  endu_testresults    index   PRIMARY    endu_testresults_a65b2616    5   NULL    19  Using index
```

Index sort column base_yob (endu_testresults_a65b2616) is now used.

**Why is that in one case index is used and in other I got 'using filesort;using temporary ?**  Does size matters ? I will try to copy records from one to another but do not get it with indexes. MySql is 5.6.16

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  Because it is faster.

Long answer...

Your EXPLAINs seem to be incomplete -- I would expect 2 lines in each.

The first table is 20 (70?) times as big as the second.  The optimizer picked the smaller table to start with.  Hence it is initially doing 1/20th the amount of work.  The sort that comes later (`ORDER BY ...`) is much less work than if it had to do 20 times as much work to start with.

The output is only 48K rows, correct?  And that is how many rows in the 2nd table, correct?

Your `test` tables did not have the same bigger/smaller ratio, did they?  Hence the different `EXPLAIN`.